# No display with Ubuntu amd open source driver

Tags: drivers, kernel, 16.04, display, amd-graphics

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS few days back. Since then I'm facing this annoying issue with open source drivers. When I start my laptop, 8 in 10 times I get no display, I have to force restart it. Even after the restart there is no display. When I boot Ubuntu, I see Ubuntu flash screen then everything goes wrong. Actually I'm facing this problem with linux for a long time. Previously I used Arch linux then I shifted to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (here no problem with open source driver). Previously, the solution was to install proprietary drivers but in Ubuntu 16.04 there is no scope for that. Even if my laptop starts when I put it on sleep and after waking it up there is no display.
What shell I do?

Answer (score 1):

I just removed "quiet splash" from kernel parameters and it's working fine now. I don't know the reason behind the issue, maybe it is because of hybrid graphic cards.